# MongoDB (PHP) - MapReduce - Connect Documents in different collections with the same ID

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a collection named **requests** with documents following this prototype:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$id": "56295368ef2b8e5458000029"
  },
  "title": "Hardcoded Name",
  "requestorId": "dve34gegrgeefdsfewe"
}
```

The `requestorId` of those documents correlates with the `id` (not the `_id` Mongo Object ID) of the **users** collection, whose documents follow this prototype:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$id": "86235288ef2gif5458000027"
  },
  "id": "dve34gegrgeefdsfewe",
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

I need to be able to run a `find()` on the **requests** collection and obtain the `name` associated with the `requestorId` in each request document. I would normally just do the obvious: run a `find()` on `requests`, then while looping through each document, do a subsequent query on **users** where `id = [requestorId (really "id" in users collection)]`, BUT I need to be able to sort the entire **requests** collection by the name associated with each `requestorId`, then use `skip()` & `limit()`. This should be pretty simple but I can't seem to figure it out... Here's my code so far, inspired by https://www.noppanit.com/merge-documents-two-collections-together-mongodb/

```
$m = new MongoClient(); // connect
$db = $m->{"database"};

// construct map and reduce functions
$eventRequest_map = new MongoCode("function() { 
    emit(this.requestorId, {\"requestorId\" : this.requestorId}) 
}");
$user_map = new MongoCode("function() { 
    emit(this.id, {\"name\" : this.name})
}");


$reductionFunction = new MongoCode("function(key, values) {
    var result = {
        \"requestorId\" : \"\",
        \"name\" : \"\"
    };

    return result;
}");

$sales = $db->command(array(
    'mapreduce' => "requests", 
    'map' => $eventRequest_map,
    'reduce' => $reductionFunction,
    'query' => array(),
    'out' => 'joined'));

$sales = $db->command(array(
    'mapreduce' => "users", 
    'map' => $user_map,
    'reduce' => $reductionFunction,
    'query' => array(),
    'out' => 'joined'));


$collection = $db->joined;

$cursor = $collection->find();
$outputJoined = array();
foreach($cursor as $doc){
    $outputJoined[] = $doc;
}
echo json_encode($outputJoined);
```